# using scanners to read/find a specific section

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java, like many others who ask questions on here, and am curious:

I know you can use scanners to read a file, eg:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("thing.txt")).useDelimiter(", ");
```

But is there a way to use scanners to read a specific part?

if I use

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

It will read out everything in the file as long as it's valid, how can I make it only read a specific section?

Comment: Why not mess around with the text that has been read instead of a workaround in the Scanner class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want some kind of separating class use StringTokenizer and specify separator. When you create separate rows search each for info. Nothing smart, but machine will do it fast...

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for some specific string or pattern in the file you can use [scanner.findWithinHorizon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Otherwise you can use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class.

Comment: This is getting close, but it's not quite what I meant. I'm not looking for a specific string, but finding what is at a certain point. for example, if there is a .txt file with a bunch of different words, like a dictionary, all separated with ", " in between them, how could I use a int or double to find what word or combo of words is at that point? imagine a list                "Hint, Nudge, Head, Torso, Fetus", and each of those would be predetermined to be a number, eg Fetus is 5, and Torso is 4. How could I reference a number instead of a string?